# download the files saved in the ios app

Tags: ios, xcode, ftp, download, sandbox

I am designing an ios app which collects the user data and saves the data into a .txt file. I am currently using the sandbox in organizer in xcode to download these files. However, I want the users who do not have xcode to access these files as well.

So are there any ways that I can download these files either via USB, or via FTP to a server, or via iCloud, or via Bluetooth, or via WIFI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iTunes File Sharing would probably be the easiest method of getting files out of your app. You basically just add the `UIFileSharingEnabled` key to your app's Info.plist, then save the file to the sandbox's `~/Documents/` directory.

[Here's a tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/itunes-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app) if you want a more in-depth discussion of how to use file sharing.

Comment: If the files are not that big, sending them via email would be nice too. Since it doesn't requires itunes.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. The files are small but there are more than 50 files generated per hour. I won't use the email unless there is an easy way to compress them. @Gonzo

Comment: The UIFileSharingEnabled works well. By using the iTune, I can download the file. Is there any way to delete the files? @Austin

Comment: Not from iTunes, and there isn't any way to notify the app that the files were downloaded. You'd have to use `NSFileManager` as with any other file.

Answer (score 0):

Probably most easiest way is to dump file content to [UIPasteboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html).